# Building Linux perf from source: how to modify the install directory?

Tags: makefile, build, linux-kernel, perf

I am following [this wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Perf_tools_support_for_Intel%C2%AE_Processor_Trace) page to build `perf` from source as below:

```
PYTHON=python3 make -C tools/perf install
```

where `~/bin` will be the default build directory.

How can I change the build directory to let's say `~/bin/test`? I already have another `perf` build in `~/bin`, and I want to have the new build in a different directory.

I have tried to modify the `Makefile` (if that is how to do it), but I could not figure it out.

One last silly question: Can I just move my current `perf` build to another directory or it will screw up its links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to easily install into a different directory by specifying `prefix=...` or `DESTDIR=...` when running `make`. You will see this and other info if you run `make -C tools/perf help`:

```
$ make -C tools/perf help
...
Perf install targets:
  NOTE: documentation build requires asciidoc, xmlto packages to be installed
  HINT: use "prefix" or "DESTDIR" to install to a particular
        path like "make prefix=/usr/local install install-doc"
  install   - install compiled binaries
...
```

Make sure to pass an *absolute path* to avoid problems (you can use `realpath` for that):

```bash
PYTHON=python3 make -C tools/perf prefix=$(realpath ~/bin/test) install
```

Comment: Thanks! I was mistakenly checking 'make --help' for such option.